# Haskell: Different ways to join a list

Tags: list, haskell

If I have a list `[a,b,c,d,e]` how do I find every way of joining the elements into sub-lists while maintaining order.

The output should look something like this

```
[ [[a], [b], [c], [d]]
, [[a,b], [c], [d]]
, [[a], [b,c], [d]]
, [[a], [b], [c,d]]
, [[a,b,c], [d]]
, [[a,b], [c,d]]
, [[a,b,c,d]]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
sublists [x] = [[[x]]]
sublists (x:xs) = sublists xs >>= \(y:ys) -> [[x]:y:ys, (x:y):ys]
```

The main insight here is that there is no logical way of extending this to empty list inputs - the only viable candidate would have been `sublists [] = [[[]]]` but this introduces empty lists (which you don't want in this case).

However, this motivates a useful invariant: the inner-inner (innermost) lists can never be empty (and we make sure this remains the case by not introducing empty lists in `[[x]:y:ys, (x:y):ys]` - the only time we add new lists with `[x]`, they already have an element in them). This ensures the pattern matching in the lambda never fails.

---

As an aside, if it is any clearer, this can be trivially rewritten using do notation:

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
sublists' [x] = [[[x]]]
sublists' (x:xs) = do
    (y:ys) <- sublists' xs
    [[x]:y:ys, (x:y):ys]
```

Or `concatMap` instead of `(>>=)`:

```
sublists'' :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
sublists'' [x] = [[[x]]]
sublists'' (x:xs) = concatMap (\(y:ys) -> [[x]:y:ys, (x:y):ys]) (sublists'' xs)
```

Comment: Thank you! that works well. Any chance of a breakdown/explanation?

Comment: There is a sensible answer for the empty list, but `[[[]]]` isn't it. The components of a partition should not be empty, but a partition could have no components in exactly the case that there were no elements in the first place.